# Running a login scenario once then multiple scenarios

Tags: c#, specflow, scenarios

I want to log in once then run a couple of scenarios (lets say 7 scenarios) before closing the browser.

I used Background instead of having a Given i am loggedin in each scenario but it seems that every time a scenario is run it starts by logging in first.

This is slowing down my tests.

WHAT I WANT TO DO:

Login and run multiple scenarios on the same browser window then close it once they are done.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is Specflow Hooks.

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks

You won't be able to specify "logging in" as a step in the background, instead you'll tag each scenario that you need to be logged in for.

Example:

```
@alreadyLoggedIn
Scenario: user can see XYZ
    Given...

@alreadyLoggedIn
Scenario: user can see ABC
    Given...
```

You then just need to specify the code for "logging in" inside a method decorated with the BeforeFeature attribute. This method will only be run once for any scenario in a feature.

```
[BeforeFeature("alreadyLoggedIn")]
public void BeforeFeatureLoggedIn()
{
    // write code to log the person in
}
```

If you have different users/roles you need to test for, just create separate tags (ie adminAlreadyLoggedIn, salesAlreadyLoggedIn, etc)

Hope this gets you on the right path!

Comment: It got me into the right path.. Thank you. This is going to make a huge difference.

Comment: The other way to do this will be to include : A Backgroung which is at feature level.

Comment: @fancpi: Nope, somewhat counter-intuitively, Backgrounds are *executed before every Scenario in a Feature*, not once per Feature.  Backgrounds are a way to reduce duplicate step definitions, but they do not eliminate the execution of the steps themselves.