# I have a StepDefinition that logs in the user. I would like to run that step definition once before the test and not have to run it again

Tags: c#, specflow

I would like to run the login StepDefinition method once before the test runs. But, not after every single feature run because I have code that saves the browser state after first login

```
Given("Login User")]
public async Task GivenLoginUser()
{
    code goes here;
}
```

Comment: What unit test framework are you using with SpecFlow? If you are using MSTest, see the [assembly and class initialize and cleanup attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-members-in-unit-tests?view=vs-2022#attributes-used-to-provide-initialization-and-cleanups). If you are using another test framework, check the framework's documentation for support for one-time setup actions. At the SpecFlow level, use a hook or an intermediate binding class (driver pattern).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a login scenario once then multiple scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502978/running-a-login-scenario-once-then-multiple-scenarios)